# How do I make my post load only if it has been fetched

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

Each time I open a new post page, the data from the last post shows on the screen for a couple of miliseconds and then the new data is shown.
I have tried to check if the post is loading and set it in the state with the setIsLoading function, but it does not work.
See the code below:

```
const PostPage = ({post, setPost, isLoading, setIsLoading}) => {
  const location = useLocation()
  const pathname = location.pathname.split("/")[2]

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true)
    const fetchData = async () => {
      let res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/posts/${pathname}`)
      const postData = res.data
      setPost(postData)
      setIsLoading(false)
    }
    fetchData()
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      {!isLoading && (
        <div>
          <h1>{post.title}</h1>
          <p>{post.text}</p>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  )
}
```

These are my routes:

```
<Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact>
            {isLogged && (
              <AddPost
                posts={posts}
                setPosts={setPosts}
                postTitle={postTitle}
                setPostTitle={setPostTitle}
                postText={postText}
                setPostText={setPostText}
                setIsLoading={setIsLoading}
              />
            )}
            <div className="posts-row">
              {posts.slice(0).reverse().map(post => (
                <Post
                  key={post.id}
                  id={post.id}
                  postTitle={post.title}
                  postText={post.text}
                  isLogged={isLogged}
                  posts={posts}
                  setPosts={setPosts}
                  />
              ))}
            </div>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/posts/:id" exact>
            <PostPage
              post={post}
              setPost={setPost}
              isLoading={isLoading}
              setIsLoading={setIsLoading}
            />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
```

In App.js I have isLoading set to true, but it works only for the first post.
For the sake of React please don't report my question :D

Edit:
Post.js

```
const Post = ({postTitle, postText, isLogged, posts, setPosts, id}) => {

  const removePost = async (id) => {
    const postArray = posts.filter((post) => (post.id !== id))
    let res = await axios.delete(`http://localhost:4000/posts/${id}`)
    setPosts(postArray)
  }

  return (
    <div className="post">
      <Link to={`/posts/${id}`}>
        <strong>
          {postTitle}
        </strong>
      </Link>
      <p>{postText}</p>
      {isLogged && (
        <button onClick={() => removePost(id)}>
          ️
        </button>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: show your routes plz

Comment: I edited the original post

Answer (score 0):

Your effect hook only runs when the component is mounted for the first time. If you want to run it every time `pathname` changes, add it to its dependency array:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setIsLoading(true)
  const fetchData = async () => {
    let res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/posts/${pathname}`)
    const postData = res.data
    setPost(postData)
    setIsLoading(false)
  }
  fetchData()
}, [pathname])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `setIsLoading` inside the `fetchData` function:
and also add the `pathname` to `useEffect` dependencies and also check the `pathname` to have value:

```
const fetchData = async () => {
  setIsLoading(true);
  let res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/posts/${pathname}`);
  const postData = res.data;
  setPost(postData);
  setIsLoading(false);
};

useEffect(() => {
  if (pathname) {
    fetchData();
  }
}, [pathname]);
```

`EDIT`:
so here is what you need to do:

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const PostPage = ({ post, setPost, isLoading, setIsLoading }) => {
  const { id } = useParams();

  const fetchData = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    let res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/posts/${id}`);
    const postData = res.data;
    setPost(postData);
    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (id) {
      fetchData();
    }
  }, [id]);

  return (
    <>
      {!isLoading && (
        <div>
          <h1>{post.title}</h1>
          <p>{post.text}</p>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: @VadimSurugiu what do you mean doesn't work. after these changes the problem isn't in your `PostPage` component . create a code sandbox so I could see the whole picture of what you're trying to do https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: I can't do that, I fetch my data from a local api

Comment: What doesn't work? What are you expecting to happen? What happens instead? Details, details, details.

Comment: When I go to a new post, for a couple of miliseconds it shows the title and text from the old post, then it updates, I don't want that to happen

Comment: I've added the code from post.js where the link to the post page is, maybe that will help